Generate a list of compound labels (\cmpd{}) in auctex
Let's say I have a LaTeX document where I am using the chemnum package to keep automatic numbering of chemical compounds: MWE
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\begin{document}
Compound \cmpd{compound-one} reacts with \cmpd{compound-two} to give \cmpd{compound-three.a} and \cmpd{compound-three.b}.
\end{document}

Instead typing every time the \cmpd{} command and having to remember the given name (compound-one, compound-three.b), it would be nice to have a pop-up menu from emacs where it lists the compound names.  Something in the line of RefTeX.
I know the auto-complete package could provide a solution, but I wonder if there is a "RefTeX-like" way to to this,
